# Change in momentum from de Broglie

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

From $p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$, the textbook concluded that $\Delta p=\frac{h\Delta\lambda}{\lambda^2}$, where did this come from?
I've considered $\frac{\Delta p}{p}$ being of the same magnitude of $\frac{\Delta\lambda}{\lambda}$, but this does not give the equivalence that is stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use differentiation, or simply you can calculate $(p+\Delta p)-p$, where, p=$\frac h \lambda$ , and $p+\Delta p=\frac h {\lambda+\Delta \lambda}$, under the estimation that, $\Delta \lambda $ is small.

So, $(p+\Delta p)-p=\frac h {\lambda+\Delta \lambda}-\frac h \lambda=\frac {-h\Delta \lambda}{\lambda(\lambda+\Delta \lambda)} \approx \frac {-h\Delta \lambda}{\lambda^2} $

The negative sign would appear because, if you increase $\lambda$, i.e., $\Delta \lambda >0,p$ decreases  i.e., $\Delta p <0$

Answer (score 1):

Just differentiate your equation and you have your result

Comment: But then I would get a negative

Comment: you only care about the absolute value $\Delta p$ is a deviation, the sign doesn't matter